# performance write many record (for example 2000000) in Cassandra?

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

How to achieve best performance for writing huge number of records (for example 2000000) in Cassandra ?
I am using Scala, Datastax driver and phantom in my project. How can I insert these many records in database in a performant way?

Comment: it all depends on your cluster and how many nodes you have, and what level of consistency you want in your data can you please specify your problem a bit more.

Comment: for example i have 3 node

Comment: you can use executeAsync to write in parallel, you can use CL localOne so that only one node's write is enough then it will sync over time.

Answer (score 1):

2 Million isn't much. I would just use CQL copy from:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html

Comment: i get data from Url and save it in cassandra i dont need copy from csv file

Answer (score 1):

The best performance could be achieved by:

- using asynchronous operations;
- prepared queries;
- use consistency level `ONE` (default, don't change);
- use DCAware/TokenAware load balancing policy (default, don't change);
- increase the number of [requests per connection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/) from default 1024 to higher number, like, 32k;

But with asynchronous queries, the big problem is that you may push more requests that Cassandra may handle, and this could lead to `BusyPoolException` - to prevent this you need some kind of counting semaphore that won't allow to issue to many requests. Here is [an example of such implementation](https://github.com/alexott/datastax-vehicle-demo/blob/code-optimizations/src/main/java/com/datastax/demo/SessionLimiter.java).

Comment: I need best performance for Insert no best performance query ?could me guidance about bulk insert operation ?

Comment: Insert is also query :-) You can use unlogged batch queries but only if all rows inside the batch are in the same partition, otherwise you'll get worse performance: https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e & http://batey.info/cassandra-anti-pattern-misuse-of.html

Comment: See following example for mass data insert: https://github.com/alexott/datastax-bootcamp-project/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/bootcamp/DataLoader.java

Comment: Thanks @alex-ott :)  yes all rows inside the batch are in the same partition but I don't know Logged Batch or unLogged batch ? which one use ?

Comment: logged batch requires storing the data on other nodes so it will be replayed if current node is failed. This is an additional overhead. So it's better to use unlogged batches.